# Establish external database connection in production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, capistrano

I am trying to establish a connection to a secondary, external database on Heroku (this is a PostgreSQL db running on AWS). I am trying to find the easiest and/or best way to do this.

I have tried using a Capistrano task to copy the `database.yml` file during deployment to Heroku:

```
after "deploy:update_code","deploy:config_symlink"

namespace :deploy do

  task :config_symlink do
    run "cp #{shared_path}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

I have tried establishing the connection via Heroku config vars:

```
class Pgdb < ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => ENV['PG_ADAPTER'],
    :database => ENV['PG_DB'],
    :username => ENV['PG_USER'],
    :password => ENV['PG_PW'],
    :host => ENV['PG_HOST']
  )

  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = 'test'

  def self.getCardInfo(card_name)
    get = connection.query("SELECT * FROM test)
    get
  end
end
```

I can't find any documentation that makes sense or tells me exactly how to do this. I do not know if I'm close or way off in the attempts above. I'm looking for any solution that fixes the above attempts or any other solution to this problem.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-connectdb.html#workingapps-connectdb-rails or https://www.penflip.com/loren/blog/blob/master/postgresRDS.md - both cover the database.yml settings for connecting to RDS remotely. If `RAILS_ENV=production` (which it should be) your `database.yml` should be parsed correctly.

Comment: My database.yml is not checked into git.

Comment: @jdesilvio Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `database_url` of the `heroku config` in the format shown below:

```
postgres://<user>:<password>@<server>:<port>/<db_name>
```

For example:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://myusername:mypassword@111.111.111.11:5542/myproject_production
```

Just make sure the firewall allows the external connection to RDS.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the setting for my primary database? This is a sends art database that I want to connect to.

Comment: Any way to add a second set of credentials to `heroku config`?